# Will a metal rod kept under very bright light for a huge amount of time, be able to conduct electricity?

Tags: electricity, electrons, photoelectric-effect

I was just sitting when it came to me - will a metal rod that has been kept under bright light for a very long time, be able to conduct electricity?

I was thinking that because of photoelectric effect, all of its outer shell electrons would have gained energy from the photons from the light source and would have escaped the nucleus's attractive force. Then, by repeating the experiment and using increasingly higher energy photons, if we are able to remove a huge number of electrons from the metal rod, will it be able to conduct electricity?

Comment: You can't significantly ionize a solid because the energy of ionization is bigger than the energy of vaporization. We can, however, vaporize the sample and then ionize it. Look into the function of a sodium-vapor lamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything it will become more conductive, because you raise electrons into the conductive bands.

You could also raise electrons to be free from the metallic body with high enough photon energy, but that doesn't allow you to deplete it from all charge carriers. In fact, the level of positive charging will be extremely small, because the positive potential developing on the rod raises the energy needed for further charge removal.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove enough electrons from a *metal* rod to make it stop conducting, I expect the rod would be so positively charged that it would [simply explode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_explosion). (Each atomic nucleus in the rod is positively charged. Without enough electrons to shield them from each other and bond them, they will repel. Metals have so many conduction electrons that the Coulomb explosion should happen before you lose conductivity.) Note that the linked Wikipedia page says that Coulomb explosions do actually happen in practice when using (high-energy) lasers to cut metals.

Conceivably, you could design a *semiconductor* material with a low enough carrier density that the photoelectric effect could deplete the charge carriers without making the system disintegrate. I am not aware of any known systems that exhibit this behavior.

In any case, note that *time* is not really a factor, for the reason noted in the other answer. As you remove electrons, removing the next electron gets harder and harder as the material becomes more positively charged. At some point, your light source just isn't removing electrons from the material anymore and waiting for an absurd amount of time isn't going to help you. You really just need the light source to have a short enough wavelength (high enough per-photon energy).